# Shadowed Error while updating Apk

Tags: android, google-play

My previous version code was 1 and I updated a new apk with version code 2  but it shows shadowed error . screen shot attached for reference.  Thanks In advance

Comment: Post the error your getting by editing this post.

Comment: You haven't attached a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

"Shadowed" means you are making 2 (or more) APKs live where one of the APKs will never be delivered to anyone because one of the APKs with a higher version code will always be delivered instead.

In your case, I suspect you want to deactivate version code 1 when you publish version code 2. Make sure version code 1 is deactivated when you publish.